# Regex expression help does not end in -0 or -00

Tags: regex

I am trying to match a regex expression in a #####-#**#** format where # is any digit from 0-9.

The -#**#** suffix can be a single or double digit such as -01, -12, -1, -2, -9,etc. except **-00** and **-0**.

So far I have:

```
"^[0-9]{6}(-(?!00)[0-9]{1,2})$"
```

Which works great for everything except something like **123456-0**

How to add that exclusion?

Comment: Hard to tell if you wanted bold letters in your question or literal `*` characters

Comment: They are bolded to try and highlight the fact that second character is optional. Sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the first zero optional and assert the end of the string in the assertion `(?!0?0$)`

```
^[0-9]{6}(-(?!0?0$)[0-9]{1,2})$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tf1xdO/1).

If you don't need the extra capture group:

```
^[0-9]{6}-(?!0?0$)[0-9]{1,2}$
```

Answer (score 2):

Try ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/oFvu0d/1)):

```py
^\d{6}-(?:[1-9]|[1-9]0|\d[1-9])$
```

Comment: You could save 1 alternative `^\d{6}-(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9])$`